# Shopify - any way to tag collections?

Tags: shopify

I'm moving a shop over to Shopify. This shop has monthly shows where one time items are offered for sale, and every show is archived on a "Past Shows" page.

Naturally, every show is a collection - such as "January 1 - January 31 2014", "February 1 - February 28 2014" and so on. This dates back about 7 years, right now there are 111 and that  number increases every month.

Displaying them on their own specific page is where the question comes in. From my research it seems the best way to do something like this is using a link list, however in my testing a link list becomes unwieldy with this many links. The dashboard page for editing the link list constantly hangs; every time I add a new show it appears at the bottom of the list and then I need to drag it all the way back to the top of the page.

It works, but there must be a better way right? Is there no way to tag a collection?

Comment: My question would be, why are you placing events that happened in the past in a collection? I am perhaps ignorant here, but a collection is populated with products currently for sale, and not past events. If you want to show off an archive of past events, and add to that archive you're probably way better off building that out of a dedicated data structure you can sort and display on a page or pages. Perhaps this is more of decision on using the right tool for the job in your migration of an old site to a new one?

Comment: @DavidLazar the shop has a couple components in which items are sold. The shows are an important piece and are a source of reference to potential customers, as well as a place where unsold items from a specific show may be seen. This is just a small piece where the mold doesn't perfectly fit a specific use case but it is an ecommerce site, surely the tool is appropriate. The question is whether there is existing functionality that I may not be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tag collections, but you can tag products within collections.

If I understand your situation correctly, perhaps you could tag the products in your past show collections (or at least one product in each collection) with "past-show". Then loop through the global `collections` variable and check for each collection if `collection.all_tags` contains "past-show". That would give you all the past show collections without needing to add them to a link list, and then you can display them however you want (dropdown / links / etc.).

Comment: You could also use smart collections to dynamically bring together all products tagged with show X, and then the linklist would simply be all of the collections that have 'past show' or whatever as part of the title